# Add link to a word in a sentence

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Is there a way in JQuery to select a particular word from a sentence entered by the user and he can be able to add a link to the word what ever he wants.Note: The sentence is not hard coded, we don't know which sentence user will enter . Depending on the sentence we have to create a link to the selected word.

Comment: too little information. Also it is possible that plain JS is all you need (split for example)

Comment: I guess you could [Use JavaScript and jQuery to Get User Selected Text, and then Do Something (Useful?) With It](http://mark.koli.ch/2009/09/use-javascript-and-jquery-to-get-user-selected-text.html)

Answer (score 1):

Combining resources from [Use JavaScript and jQuery to Get User Selected Text, and then Do Something (Useful?) With It](http://mark.koli.ch/2009/09/use-javascript-and-jquery-to-get-user-selected-text.html), [wrapping text using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/727473/122005) and the part of Sridhar Narasimhan's answer below, you could come up with the following (untested):

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="enter"/>
<div id="content" ></div>
<div id="link" ></div>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$("#enter").bind("keyup", function() {
    $("#content").html($("#enter").val());
});

$.expr[":"].containsNoCase = function(el, i, m) {
    var search = m[3];
    if (!search) return false;
    // we'll use text to find what we want...
    return eval("/" + search + "/ig").test($(el).text());
};


if (!window.Kolich) {
    Kolich = {};
}

Kolich.Selector = {};
Kolich.Selector.getSelected = function() {
    var t = '';
    if (window.getSelection) {
        t = window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.getSelection) {
        t = document.getSelection();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        t = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return t;
}

$.expr[":"].containsNoCase = function(el, i, m) {
    var search = m[3];
    if (!search) return false;
    // we'll use text to find what we want...
    return eval("/" + search + "/ig").test($(el).text());
};


Kolich.Selector.mouseup = function() {
    var st = Kolich.Selector.getSelected();
    if (st != '') {
        // alert("You selected:\n" + st);
        // wrap selecetd word in a link
        $("#content:containsNoCase('" + st + "')").each(function() {
            var textwithLink = '<a href="javascript:alert(\'link-to-selected-text.htm\')">' + st + '</a>';

            $("#link").html(textwithLink);

        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).bind("mouseup", Kolich.Selector.mouseup);
});
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bGfA2/)

Comment: I have included a working demo link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3CFsd/ Bare in mind I haven't had to fully test this code but that's just the general intuition, could be impoved however.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to select entire statement, I want to add a link to a particular word using any external button

Comment: From the demo, it's not selecting the entire input but just the selected text `st`. The code is adding the link to the selected text on selection, I guess you could then handle that with the button click event.

Comment: I've updated the code to include a line with the selected text wrapped in a custom link http://jsfiddle.net/bGfA2/

Comment: If I enter "Hai Chridam" and click on 'chridam' link is adding, its ok. But next time if I click on 'hai', 'chridam' link is disappearing.Is it possible to show both links without disappearing any thing.

Comment: From the requirements, you mentioned `JQuery to select a particular word from a sentence entered by the user and he can be able to add a link to the word what ever he wants`, code above only works for a selected word or words (one-to-one relationship, that is, a link to a selection) and as far as I  know you cannot simultaneously add different links to two selections. If this solution has worked for you, please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try the below

<input type="text" id="enter"/>
    <div id="content" ></div> 



$("#enter").bind("keyup",function(){

$("#content").html($("#enter").val().replace("Jquery","<a href=''  >Jquery</a>"));
});
```

Enter Jquery in input and check it.

http://jsfiddle.net/aDRB6/11/

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Sridhar Narasimhan, Here I don't want all the data entered in the text box, i want to select a particular word and add a link to that word.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
      Your HTML Structure.
     <input type="text" id="enter"/>
     <input type="text" id="link"/>
     <button type="button" onclick="doAction()">Make Link</button>
     <div id="content" >Mrinmoy Ghoshal</div>
```

Here is Your Function

```
       function doAction(){

       var enterv=document.getElementById('enter').value;
       var linkv=document.getElementById('link').value;
       var str=document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;

       var strnew=str.replace(enterv,'<a href="'+linkv+'">'+enterv+'</a>');
       document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=strnew;
       alert(strnew);
       }
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/85tAq/2/)

Comment: Can you please send the above in fiddler

Comment: wait for a minute, I am giving you the link

Comment: sorry issue is there, once check

Comment: what issue? Please tell me

Comment: After entering text in the available fields and click on add link nothing is happening

Comment: In the first 'textbox' you have to enter the text that you are want to change and in the second textbox you have to put any link that will be placed. So Fill Both Text Box. Got it?