# Adding css to unordered list <li>

Tags: jquery

I have an unordered list

```
<ul id="List1">
    <li>www.xyz.com</li>
    <li>www.abc.com</li>
</ul>
```

using jquery, I want to convert this li to a link and add font as underline

I am trying it like this

```
$('li').css('font', 'underline').click(function () {
    // how to add hyperlink?
});
```

Comment: that's actually an "unordered list". ul = unordered list, ol = ordered list. =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this?  This will turn the elements into actual links, so you don't need to add the underline or onclick handler.

```
    $('li').each(function(e) {
        $(this).wrapInner('<a href="http://' + $(this).text() + '"></a>');
    });
```

In your example, the list items were urls, so this will only work if that remains the case.

Comment: Links are normally underlined by default - so unless you've changed the default style to remove the underlining, that code should result in underlined, clickable links.

Comment: Ok i used text-decoration and it happened. How can i add two css attributes at the same time..for eg: text-decoration and color to the <li> tag

Comment: You can use this syntax:

     $('li a').css({ "text-decoration": "underline", "color": "#333333" });

If you're changing several CSS attributes, though, I'd usually make a new class and then assign the class to the links.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the "linkify" method mentioned in this question: [jQuery Text to Link Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247479/jquery-text-to-link-script/248901#248901)