# What is the easiest way to replace a url string (in a text) with an anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, anchor, css

I have text:

`I love Stackoverflow so much, so please visist http://stackoverflow.com`

How can I transform it to:

`I love Stackoverflow so much, so please visist <a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>http://stackoverflow.com</a>`

in the easiest way in javascript?

Note that the url in text could be without `http://` and without `wwww`, but I want the attribute `href`to contain at least `http://`. Also take in consideration that some links are `https://`

Comment: http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=URL&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Text to Link Script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247479/jquery-text-to-link-script)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace plain URLs with links?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links)

Comment: Can somone pls tell me an answer for url strings that doesn't contain `http://` or/and `www` in the url? Given this regex `/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;` from @mplungjan's link?

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

```
var text = 'I love Stackoverflow so much, so please visist http://stackoverflow.com';
result = text.replace(/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[\-A-Z09+&@#\/%=~_|])/img, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
alert(result);
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/5cKhn/

RegEx taken from RegEx library within [RegEx Buddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Comment: So taking this already posted answer: [How to replace plain URLs with links?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links/37687#37687), adding a slash and an m, and no credits makes this a good answer?

Comment: @mplungjan, I genuinely hadn't seen that answer. I'd only looked at the duplicate reported by Haim Evgi. I took the regex from the regex library in RegEx Buddy - I'll change the answer to credit that.

Comment: @ipr101: Can you create regex for urls that doesn't contain `http://`and `www` too in RegEx Buddy? Like `stackoverflow.com` becomes `<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow.com</a>` and `www.stackoverflow.com` becomes `<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">www.stackoverflow.com</a>`

Comment: @Woho87 That would be more difficult as you'd have to define what was and wasn't a URL. For instance, `stackoverflow.com` is a sequence of characters then a dot then another sequence of characters, so you might pick-up other non-url matches using that logic. You'd really have to decide the rules you wanted to use to match a URL then take it from there.

Comment: You could look for location.host in the text to at least convert the links that mentioned the current server